# Find the muscle and fat mask of an ROI in an MRI slice while ignoring background pixels

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an ROI of a muscle from an MRI slice. I want to separate the muscle and fat pixels in the ROI to get the ratio of each tissue type. However, when doing the thresholding, the background pixels (zero-padded) are thresholded as muscle. I am not sure how to only threshold the ROI pixels. This is the closest I could get to the solution I am looking for. Attached is the ROI image and the output for this code. Thanks!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def separate_muscle_fat_ignore_padding(mri_slice):
    """
    Separates the muscle and fat regions in an MRI slice while ignoring the zero padding.
    
    Args:
        mri_slice (ndarray): Grayscale MRI slice.
    
    Returns:
        tuple: Binary segmentation masks for muscle and fat regions.

    """
    # Exclude zero padding pixels
    nonzero_pixels = np.nonzero(mri_slice)
    min_y, max_y = np.min(nonzero_pixels[0]), np.max(nonzero_pixels[0])
    min_x, max_x = np.min(nonzero_pixels[1]), np.max(nonzero_pixels[1])
    mri_slice = mri_slice[min_y:max_y+1, min_x:max_x+1]

    # Apply thresholding to segment muscle and fat
    _, binary_fat = cv2.threshold(mri_slice, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    binary_muscle = cv2.bitwise_not(binary_fat)

    return binary_muscle, binary_fat


# Load grayscale MRI slice
mri_slice = cv2.imread('masked_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Separate muscle and fat regions while ignoring zero padding
muscle_mask, fat_mask = separate_muscle_fat_ignore_padding(mri_slice)

# Display the original slice and the segmented masks
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(mri_slice, cmap='gray')
plt.title('MRI Slice')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(muscle_mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Muscle Mask')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(fat_mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Fat Mask')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: masked_image.jpg]
[image: output]